# Django and react browser router shows only css

Tags: reactjs, django

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def home4(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

urls.py

```
path('a/',views.home,name='home'),
path('b/',views.home4,name='home4'),
```

App.js

```
import './App.css'
...
<BrowserRouter>
        <Route path='/a' element={<Form/>} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

When I got to /a it doesn't show the form component(it is just a form) but the css works.